# Unable to understand MUP error in meteor

Tags: javascript, logging, meteor, meteor-up

I am getting the error below in Meteor. Can anyone please help in explaining what might be the problem? This has been deploying fine just till now (I have made several code changes that are working without error in development)

```
-----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/0.10.36',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/opt/cyclusbreak/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
gyp info ok
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------
b.node
make: Leaving directory `/opt/cyclusbreak/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'

> fibers@1.0.5 install /opt/cyclusbreak/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node ./build.js

`linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
underscore@1.5.2 node_modules/underscore

eachline@2.3.3 node_modules/eachline
└── type-of@2.0.1

chalk@0.5.1 node_modules/chalk
├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.3
├── supports-color@0.2.0
├── has-ansi@0.1.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)
└── strip-ansi@0.3.0 (ansi-regex@0.2.1)

semver@4.1.0 node_modules/semver

source-map-support@0.2.8 node_modules/source-map-support
└── source-map@0.1.32 (amdefine@0.1.0)

fibers@1.0.5 node_modules/fibers
Waiting for MongoDB to initialize. (5 minutes)
connected
cyclusbreak stop/waiting
cyclusbreak start/running, process 4278
Waiting for 15 seconds while app is booting up
Checking is app booted or not?
cyclusbreak stop/waiting
cyclusbreak start/running, process 4376
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Meteor and Node are you using?

You can run `mup logs -n 400` on the project folder and see if there's any helpful information on the logs. I had a similar error and it was that Meteor 1.2 required node's v0.10.40 or greater.

It seems you're using 0.10.36 so you might need to change the nodeVersion in your `mup.json` file to the proper one and run `mup setup` again.